# retrieving information from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have three tables:

```
users:
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------+
| users_id | user detail                 | otherID   | 
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------+
|        1 | user name or details        |         1 |
|        2 | user name or details        |         1 |
|        3 | user name or details        |         4 |
|        4 | user name or details        |         1 |
|        5 | user name or details        |       21  |
|        6 | user name or details        |         2 |
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------+
photos:
+----------+----------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------+
| photosID | url            |    title  | userID | likes   | remarksID    |
+----------+----------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------+
|      1   |       7459.JPG |   TITLE   |      1 |     150 |       255    |
|      2   |       7510.JPG |   TITLE   |      1 |     146 |       247    |
|      3   |       7460.JPG |   TITLE   |      2 |       2 |        56    |
+----------+----------------+-----------+--------+---------+--------------+

remarks:
+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+------------+
| remarksID | remark                                | userID  | photoID    |
+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+------------+
|         1 | REMARKS for PhotoID 1                 |       1 |          1 |
|         2 | REMARKS for PhotoID 1                 |       1 |          1 |
|         3 | REMARKS for PhotoID 1                 |       1 |          1 |
|         4 | REMARKS for PhotoID 2                 |       1 |          2 |
|         5 | REMARKS for PhotoID 2                 |       1 |          2 |
|         6 | REMARKS for PhotoID 3                 |       2 |          3 |
+-----------+---------------------------------------+---------+------------+
```

I am trying to extract the remarks for a given users photo, but only want the photo to appear once but all the relevant remarks for the photo to be displayed for each users photo.
If there are no remarks then just display the photo without remarks.

The layout would look like this on a web page-

```
------------------------------------
Photograph 1
         Remarks 1
         Remarks 2
         Remarks 1
------------------------------------
Photograph 2
         NO remarks for photo
------------------------------------
Photograph 3
         Remarks 1
         Remarks 2
         Remarks 3
         Remarks 4
------------------------------------
Photograph 4
         Remarks 1
         Remarks 2
------------------------------------
```

Comment: and which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: well the display pattern you are looking for is not possible using mysql as already mentioned by Charles Bretana, the application should do it of its own. However to shrink down the result set you can use group_concat() to get all the remarks for a photo of the user then in the application level read the result set and then split the remarks and generate the view.

Answer (score 0):

Is my assumption correct that your difficulty is, how to get the database to do this? If so, then the answer is that this function (formatting the data), is not (or should not) generally be the responsibility of the database.  Fetch the photos from the database as one result set, then fetch the matching comments in another, and let your application or reporting tool format the data the way you want it.

Comment: Hi I understand the formatting of the question is the retrieval that is the problem. I have been trying LEFT JOIN but have seen a post about SUB SELECT statement and are not sure if I have been going down the wrong path.

Comment: What I am suggesting is Don't try to do the joins in the database in a single sql statement, run separate statements for the photos, and the comments, and join and format the data in your application and/or your reporting tool

Comment: Ok so I'm over complicating things then LOL many thanks for the advice appreciate it.